# Block sliding down a table

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

**Disclaimer:** I came up with the following problem on my own, so I don't know if there is a solution that makes sense our if my approach to solving it is correct... Any help is appreciated.

---

Consider the following situation: A rectangle of length $l=0.1$ and width $b=0.02$ is sliding along a table with some initial velocity. I'd like to calculate the trajectory and the time until it loses contact to the table.

My idea here was to use Lagrangian mechanics. To simplify the explanation I drew the following sketch for some time $t>0$.
[image]
The red dot should represent the center of mass and $s$ the distance between the center of mass and the point of rotation (lets set the center of our coordinate system there). We can now write the center of mass as

$$\vec{r}(t) = \begin{pmatrix}s(t)\cos\theta(t) + \frac{b}{2}\sin\theta(t)\\ -s(t)\sin\theta(t) +\frac{b}{2}\cos\theta(t)\end{pmatrix}. $$

%With this we are able to write down the Lagrangian in the form
$$L= T-V =\frac{1}{2}m\dot{\vec{r}}^2+\frac{1}{2}J\dot\theta^2+mgs\sin\theta-\frac{mgb}{2}\cos\theta.$$

We further find
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}m\dot{\vec{r}}^2 &= \frac{1}{8} m (4 {\dot s}^2 +4 b \dot s\dot\theta + (b^2 + 4 s^2) \dot\theta^2)\\
\frac{1}{2}J\dot\theta^2 &= \frac{1}{2} (\frac{1}{12} m (l^2 + b^2) + m s^2) \dot\theta^2
\end{align*},$$
where I used the parallel axis theorem. All of this together gives
$$L = \frac{1}{24}(l^2\dot\theta^2+4b^2\dot\theta^2+24s\dot\theta^2+12\dot s^2+ 12 b\dot s \dot\theta+24gs\sin\theta -12bg\cos\theta).$$
The equations of motion are then given by
$$\begin{align*} 
 \dot\theta^2 +g \sin\theta &=\ddot s + \frac{1}{2}b\ddot\theta\\ 
\left(\frac{1}{12}l^2+\frac{1}{3}b^2\right)\ddot\theta+\frac{1}{2}b\ddot s &= \frac{1}{2}bg\sin\theta-2\dot s\dot\theta-gs\cos\theta. 
\end{align*}$$

The condition for the rectangle to lose contact to the table is given by 
$$[\ddot{\vec{r}}]_x=0 \Longleftrightarrow \frac{d^2}{dt^2}(-s(t)\sin\theta(t) +\frac{b}{2}\cos\theta(t)) =0$$
This equation should in principle be enough to determine the time $t^*$ when the rectangle leaves the table.

---

Let us assume that we also have the following initial conditions
$$s(0)=0.01,\quad \dot s(0)= 0.3,\quad u(0)= 0,\quad \dot u(0)= 0.$$
Since you can't solve this analytically I tried it numerically ([Mathematica code](https://pastebin.com/8jKhpnNr)) and got the following plots 
[image]
I then tried to find $t^*$ using my approximate solutions for $s$ and $\theta$ but if you plot $[\ddot{\vec{r}}]_x$ against $t$ you get

[image]

which clearly doesn't have a zero at all...

I checked the Mathematica code multiple times and also checked for calculation errors up to arriving at the ODE's, but I can't find an error which leads me to believe that I have a more fundamental problem in my approach. Do you see something obvious (or not so obvious) that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You get $s(t)>100 [m]$ impossible. I think that the if $s(t) >l/2$ the rod lose contact.

Comment: @Eli It should lose contact a lot sooner... Just take a book, apply some force (such that its horizontal velocity isn't zero) and you'll see that the end of the book probably won't touch the rotating point.

Comment: I understand you came up with this problem on your own, but I still feel like it fits with the "homework-and-exercises" tag, since it is essentially an exercise in Lagrangian mechanics and plotting results from such work. It is not meant to be a put-down to the question though. It is an interesting problem

Comment: I haven't looked at your equations, but your graph for $\theta$ over time seems very odd.  I'd expect it to accelerate, not decelerate.

Comment: I am confused by your notation. It looks like the center of mass is just described by the $s$ vector if you put your origin at the corner. What is this $b$ term for?

Comment: @AaronStevens The term $b$ is meant to represent the width of the rectangle.

Comment: Oh ok... interesting. Maybe your analysis would be a lot easier if you neglected the width? Unless you wanted to consider scenarios where the width is actually not negligible compared to the length.

Comment: @AaronStevens The equations of motion would certainly simplify, but Mathematica also suggests that the solutions wouldn't change significantly. In my mind the rectangle should for example approximate a book and in such a scenario it seems a bit much to just neglect the width..

Comment: @BowlOfRed I agree with you. I can't really imagine that the constraint of being connected to the table should make such a difference, but as mentioned, I don't really see where I fail in the mathematics...

Comment: @BowlOfRed I was just thinking that the plot for $\theta$ maybe does make sense... If we consider how the system is set up, shouldn‘t we expect the angle to be $\le 90^\circ$, since the rectangle is fixed to the table and would therefore move vertically along the table (where one point always touches the table)? Looking at the plot it seems that it actually could converge to $\pi/2$

Comment: Where is the constraint equation? As far as i know, you have to add another parameter in your Euler equation. See Lagrange's equations of the first kind

Comment: @paradoxy fair point.. My initial idea was to use $\ddot r_x = 0$ as constraint to figure out the time $t^*$ when the rectangle gets separated from the table, from then on the equation describing the evolution of the angle would be $\theta_{new} (t) = \dot\theta(t^*) t + \theta(t^*)$ which just arises from the fact that after the rectangle gets separated from the table the eom for rotation and translation are not coupled anymore... But again, dor this I would need to find $t^*$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I just want to point an error in the ODE's of the original post.  I can tell just by looking at them that they are both wrong, because they do not make sense dimensionally.  If we look at the first one:
\begin{align*} 
 \dot\theta^2 +g \sin\theta &=\ddot s + \frac{1}{2}b\ddot\theta\
\end{align*}

Everything has dimension of acceleration in this equation, except $\dot \theta^2$, so you probably forgot an $s$ or a $b$ along the way. Note that my solution also get rid of the parallel axis theorem, which I will explain why.

Here's my solution. I use the same coordinates as the original post.
 $\vec{r}(t) = \begin{pmatrix}s(t)\cos\theta(t) + \frac{b}{2}\sin\theta(t)\\ -s(t)\sin\theta(t) +\frac{b}{2}\cos\theta(t)\end{pmatrix}$

Then:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}m\dot{\vec{r}}^2 &= \frac{1}{8} m (4 {\dot s}^2 +4 b \dot s\dot\theta + (b^2 + 4 s^2) \dot\theta^2)\\
\frac{1}{2}J\dot\theta^2 &= \frac{1}{2} (\frac{1}{12} m (l^2 + b^2) \dot\theta^2
\end{align*}

Here's the key thing: You do not use the parrallel axis theorem, because then you are "overcounting" the motion of your center of mass. We only want the energy coming from the rotation of the body around its center of mass. How do we find it?  Well, we know that instantaneously the center of mass rotates with angular velocity $\dot\theta$ around the corner of the plane. But from the perspective of the center of mass, the corner (i.e. the block) rotates with angular velocity $\dot\theta$ around the center of mass.  Therefore the body rotates around its center of mass with angular velocity $\dot\theta$, so the rotationnal energy term is simply 
$\frac{1}{2}J\dot\theta^2 = \frac{1}{2} (\frac{1}{12} m (l^2 + b^2) \dot\theta^2$,
where $J$ is the usual moment of inertia of a block around its CM.

The Lagrangian is:
$L = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{\vec{r}}^2 + \frac{1}{2}J\dot\theta^2 - mg(-s\sin\theta +\frac{b}{2}\cos\theta)$.

The ODE's I get are:
\begin{align*} 
 s\dot\theta^2 +g \sin\theta &=\ddot s + \frac{1}{2}b\ddot\theta\\ 
\left(\frac{1}{12}l^2+\frac{1}{3}b^2+s^2\right)\ddot\theta+\frac{1}{2}b\ddot s + 2s\dot s\dot \theta &= \frac{1}{2} g b \sin \theta + gs\cos \theta . 
\end{align*}

The block looses contact when $\ddot \theta =0$, since the body will simply keep rotating about its CM with whatever last angular velocity it had when it left the plane. Using the initial conditions given in the originl post, we get the following plot for $\ddot \theta$:

[image]

The block looses contact at about 0.095 s.  This result does make intuitive sense when looking at the intial velocity and at the length of the block.

Comment: I have the same equations of motions, but I got different looses contact time?

Comment: The block looses contact when the contact force is  zero?

Comment: @Eli Just checked Shamaz 's calculation and I get the same time as he with the condition of the force in $x$-direction being zero.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think that this is the  solution:

I put a body fixed coordinate system at the center of mass of the rechtangle , so the position vector is:
$$\vec{r}=\begin{pmatrix}
  \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
  \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
   -s\\
   b/2\\
\end{pmatrix}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} -\cos \left( \theta \right) s-1/2\,\sin
 \left( \theta \right) b\\ -\sin \left( \theta
 \right) s+1/2\,\cos \left( \theta \right) b\end {array} \right] 
$$
The kinetic energy is:
$$T=\frac{1}{2}\,m\,\vec{\dot{r}}^T\,\vec{\dot{r}}=\left( 1/2\,m{s}^{2}+1/8\,m{b}^{2}+1/2\,J \right) {\dot{\theta}}^{2}+1/2
\,m{\it \dot{s}}\,\dot{\theta}\,b+1/2\,{{\it \dot{s}}}^{2}m$$
where $J$ is the Inertia of the  rectangle at the center of mass.

The potential  energy is:
$$V=mg \left( -\sin \left( \theta \right) s+1/2\,\cos \left( \theta
 \right) b \right)
$$
The equations of motion:
$${\frac {d^{2}}{d{\tau}^{2}}}s \left( \tau \right) ={\frac {mbs\theta p
\,{\it sp}}{m{s}^{2}+J}}+1/4\,{\frac { \left( m{b}^{2}s+4\,Js+4\,m{s}^
{3} \right) {\theta p}^{2}}{m{s}^{2}+J}}+1/4\,{\frac {4\,Jg\sin
 \left( \theta \right) +4\,m{s}^{2}g\sin \left( \theta \right) -2\,mbg
\cos \left( \theta \right) s}{m{s}^{2}+J}}
$$
and
$${\frac {d^{2}}{d{\tau}^{2}}}\theta \left( \tau \right) =-2\,{\frac {ms
\theta p\,{\it sp}}{m{s}^{2}+J}}-1/2\,{\frac {mbs{\theta p}^{2}}{m{s}^
{2}+J}}+{\frac {mgs\cos \left( \theta \right) }{m{s}^{2}+J}}
$$
where $sp=\dot{s}$ and $\theta p=\dot{\theta}$

Simulation:

we solve the equations of motion numerically with $J=1/12\,m(l^2+b^2)$ .

Because the constraint force between the table and the rectangle is proportional to the acceleration of the rectangle in space coordinate system, we can check  the condition where is no contact between the rectangle and table and find the time where the contact froce equal zero.

$F_x\propto\,\vec{\ddot{r}}_x=0$

Where $F_x$ is the contact force toward the x space axis.

result $\vec{\ddot{r}}_x$ over t

[image]

so for $t=0.114$[s] there is no contact between the rectangle and the table.

Comment: Once again, can you explain to me why you are ignoring the axis around which the rectangle rotates? The moment of inertia changes according to the axis of rotation and if I‘m reading your equations correctly, you are assuming a rotation around the center of mass, which is not what is happening...

Comment: no t don't think so, the coordinate is body fix at the center of mass.I add a figure

Comment: Right now I don‘t see it, so I‘ll need to think about it later... Probably my first question would be what exactly $r(t)$ describes in your choosen coordinate frame...

Comment: $\vec{r}$ is the position vector of the center of mass in space coordinate system.

Comment: That doesn‘t really make sense... If you choose the center of mass frame then by definition the center of mass will always be at the origin of your chosen coordinate system... And since $\vec{r}(t)$ changes with time that doesen‘t add up...

Comment: I just checked it, but as suspected, the only thing that separates your calculation from mine is that you leave out the parallel axis theorem... Meaining that if I change in my calculation $J=\frac{1}{12} m (l^2 + b^2) + m s^2$ to $J' = \frac{1}{12} m (l^2 + b^2)$ I get the exact same result as you. But since this change doesn't make sense in the context of this question, I suspect that something went wrong in your calculation...

Comment: Yup. You have to use parallel axis theorem here